# Is this safe from compiler optimisation?

Tags: c++, recursion, optimization

Being somewhat paranoid nowadays about being caught out by compiler optimisations, I'd like an opinion about the validity of the following code.
The base class is part of a common framework, but the derived would be created by a user of said framework.

The idea behind the example is that the user 'Process' function in the user derived class may call the 'ProcessMessage' in the framework base, causing a recursive call. If a recursive call has occurred then the message is queued for later processing.

The question is, are the two 'processing' flags around the call to the derived function safe from compiler optimisation?

```
//*************************************
// Framework code.
//*************************************
template <typename TDerived>
class Base
{
public:

  Base()
    : processing(false)
  {
  }

  void ProcessMessage(int msg)
  {
    if (processing)
    {
      // Queue the message for later.
    }
    else
    {
      processing = true; // Are these safe from optimisation?

      // Calls user derived class function
      static_cast<TDerived&>(*this).Process(msg);

      processing = false; // Are these safe from optimisation?
    }
  }

private:

  bool processing;
};

//*************************************
// User code.
//*************************************
class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:

  void Process(int msg)
  {
    if ((msg % 4) == 0)
    {
      this->ProcessMessage(msg); // Recursive call.
    }
  }
};

int main()
{
  Derived derived;

  derived.ProcessMessage(0);
  derived.ProcessMessage(1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you have to be more specific what you expect as "being safe from compiler optimizations". What do you expect or worry about? The compiler can always decide to generate code that behaves equivalent, e.g. when it can prove that the queuing branch is never taken.

Comment: They're not safe from exceptions. If `Process()` throws, `processing` will never reset to `false`.

Comment: What's the desired behavior after all?

Comment: If two threads call ProcessMessage without synchronization it's a data race and therefore undefined behavior. (you didn't specify in your question if the code can be called concurrently or not)

Comment: "safe from compiler optimisation" I fear it's an ill-defined notion. The code either has UB, or it does not. If it does, it is not safe.

Comment: The calls to ProcessMessage will always be from the same thread.

I was paranoid about the compiler seeing 'processing' being set to true, then false, and optimising it away as 'redundant'.

Answer (score 2):

The standard you find:

> **intro.execution.16**
>
> Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated.

So your program is 'safe from optimization'. But as stated in the comments you may still have problems with exceptions or concurrency.